# How to find public drinking fountains when travelling?

Tags: tap-water

When travelling for a long period of time, refilling water bottles can be a challenge.  This is particularly true for long overland public transportation journeys in summer, as one cannot easily carry as much water as when travelling by car.

The availability of public drinking water fountains varies widely between countries and cities, as does information about such fountains.  The topic regularly comes up on this site:

- [Are there drinking water fountains airside at London City Airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45778/2509)
- [Are there any drinking-water fountains in Prague PRG airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/51721/2509)
- [Are there drinking water fountains at Birmingham Airport (UK)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/61389/2509)
- [Where to find public water taps in the Netherlands?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/36473/2509)
- [Is it safe to drink the water in the fountains found all over the older parts of Rome?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/150735/2509)
- [Where to refill my bottle in India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/135278/2509)
- ... etc.

I'm looking for a *generic* solution to this problem.

Is there any website or smartphone application that travellers can use internationally to locate a source of (free) drinking water?  I'm aware the data would probably have to be crowd-sourced.  Openstreetmap has [Tag:amenity=drinking_water](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Ddrinking_water), [Tag:man_made=drinking_fountain](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:man_made%3Ddrinking_fountain), and [Tag:drinking_water=yes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:drinking_water), but I don't know how to easily search for such categories while travelling, and there may be more complete sources that I'm unaware of.

*(The safety of such water is a separate issue that I will consider out of the scope of this question.)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a web-based Openstreetmap interface, one can use [taginfo.openstreetmap.org](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org).  For example, [here is the taginfo for `amenity=drinking_water`](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/tags/amenity=drinking_water#map).  From there, one can click on *Overpass turbo* in the top right to be directed to https://overpass-turbo.eu/.  Pan and zoom the map to the area of interest and click *Run*.

For example, [this is the result near Barcelona Sants station](https://preview.tinyurl.com/v5nkvgo):

[image: Screenshot of overpass-turbo]

Or in central Frankfurt, where Openstreetmap contains no results near the main train station:

[image]

Through the export-button, you can download a GPX file that you can download into a handheld GNSS-capable device.

Relevant comment by nrainer:

> If you are using OsmAnd you can also show the information on the map by searching for "drinking water" and clicking on the button "show on map".

Comment: As with most, if not all OSM features, the coverage is only sporadic and data quality difficult to predict. I checked a few areas I know fairly well and no water sources were mapped, although I know several. I don't think this is a particularly good suggestion if you are looking for a generic solution.

Comment: OpenCYCLEmap shows drinking water by default, from the same dataset (maybe the similar question I mentioned above was at bicycles.stackexchange.com and that's why I can't find it here)

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I'd be happy to get other solutions, even if those are only more complete than OSM in certain regions.

Comment: @ChrisH Showing on a busy map is one thing (OSM default view does show them if you zoom closely enough), "find me the closest" is also particularly useful.

Comment: If you are using OsmAnd you can also show the information on the map by searching for "drinking water" and clicking on the button "show on map".

Comment: @nrainer Thanks; I have included this information in the answer.